# Cypress split string for test

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

i need to parse a string in cypress. i am trying to grab a piece of string with the methods provided by javascript. but it doesn't work gives me an error:

type i have this string:

```
text2 = "change status id 423 in Cult"
text1 = 423

var id = text2.split (' ')
expect (text1).to.eq(id[3])
```

how can i do such a thing in cypress. I should take part of a string and compare it but with the split method it gives me an error

below the error returned:
[image]

Comment: Pls add the error so we can debug the situation

Comment: Edit: First - it seems you arenet selecting any text

Second: It seems like it fails because it is a JQuery element. Try using cy.wrap(text2).split(' ')>

Comment: @bigeyes What do you get when you use `cy.log(text2)`

Comment: I updated the post image @AlapanDas with cy.log(text2) is highlighted in purple

Comment: if i put cy.wrap(text2).split(' ') get the following error cy.wrap(...).split is not a function @RosenMihaylov

Comment: otherwise it would be enough for me to say that id: 412 (a random number) is contained in text2 but I don't know if there is such an assertion in cypress @AlapanDas

Comment: @bigeyes can you try this and let me know what does it log - `cy.get('p.text-lg').invoke('text').then((text) => {
    var splitText = text.split(' ')[5]
    cy.log(splitText)
})`

Comment: OK now it works but I don't understand why @AlapanDas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [then()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/then.html#Syntax) instead of [should()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Arguments) -

```
cy.get('p.text-lg').invoke('text').then((text) => {
    var splitText = text.split(' ')[5]
    expect(splitText).to.equal(291)
})
```

Comment: what is the difference between using should and then ?

Comment: There is no difference between the `text` parameter when running  `then()` vs `should()` with a callback, something else has affected the result.

Comment: The main difference between `then()` and `should()` is that `should()` will retry the `expect()` if it fails - `then()` will only run the callback code once.

Comment: Why are you suggesting `var splitText = text.split(' ')[5]` ?

Comment: @RosenMihaylov its because OP wanted to extract only the number from the sentence and the position of the number in the sentence was sixth, as per the screenshot attached.